# Escaping comma inside double quotes in sql

Tags: csv, oracle11g, hxtt

I have a csv file which contains a column with values inside the double quotes. Few of the values inside the double quotes also contains commas(Example "Alexandar, the Third").

I am using the below hxtt properties to read the file from the location loc and to read headers and double quotes : 
jdbc:csv:////?_CSV_Header=true;_CSV_Quoter=";

Is there any hxtt properties that I can use to read the full content inside the double quotes or is it possible to handle it in sql query? Could you please help me? Also, please note I am using sql query to read the values from the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your values delimited by single quotes instead of double quotes.
Commas won't be an issue then. But if your values contain single quotes(or other special characters) you need to excape them using another single quote.
So 'Alexander's Castle' would be 'Alexander''s Castle'.